# How to modify file on windowsapp folder

Tags: windows-8, security, permissions

I have been trying to modify and add content to a app folder. But for some reason it does not allow me to modify or add new content to that folder.

These are the things I have done:

1) Take ownership.
2) Write permission to my username and groups.
3) Removed all other permissions and added the user "everyone"
4) Root folder and parent folder all have the same exactly permissions.

I am guessing this is a special folder, maybe its a folder that Microsoft made to not allow user modify it?

If you came across this issue before and manage a solution please let me know.

Comment: What is the path of this "app folder"?  Also, when you took ownership, did you check the box that says, "Replace owner on subcontainers and objects"?

Comment: Hi @Jason, yes I did all of that. This is the path. "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps", this is a hidden folder. Also this path might be different to yours. I am using windows 8.1

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? This is really annoying.